# Is a path-connected space equipped with local charts a manifold?

Tags: general-topology

Path connected space: for any two points $a$ and $b$ in the space, there is a continuous map $f$ from interval $[0,1]$ to the space such that $f(0)=a, f(1)=b$.

To show it is a manifold, we need to show that it satisfies the following:

1. second countable
2. hausdorff space
3. local charts

I think it depends on the first point.
It is a Hausdorff space because the interval $[0,1]$ is.

Comment: No it is not. Look up the line with two origins.

Comment: @Nico I see. But in that case the function from the interval to the path would no longer be surjective, as the other zero has no domain. What do we call a path connected space with the requirement that the mapping function be bijective?

Comment: You mean [arc connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Arc_connectedness) space?

Comment: All three properties in the deflation of a manifold are independent from each other even if you assume path-connectivity. But it seems that you want your space to admit a continuous bijective map from an interval. That's too much to ask.